# Installing serializer without composer - symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

While I am trying to install serializer i am getting this error - The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on on your PHP installation.
My host provider said that he cant change it for me.

Is there other option to install Seriazlizer, and how can I do that?

Thank u.

Comment: Are you trying to run the `composer install` or `composer update` command on your hosting server? One option would be to do that all locally on your own computer, and then upload the finished `/vendor` directory along with the rest of your symfony app.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but is there option to install it without composer ?

Comment: Sure, download the github repo yourself. But you'll want composer's autoloader to help you locate and load the classes anyway, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install on your computer a local composer repository for example : Satis https://github.com/composer/satis
2. Create a satis.json and build satis

   ```
   php satis/bin/satis build satis.json server-composer/
   ```
3. Install a webserver
4. Dump the generated folder on the host provider in webserver root folder.
5. Add your new local repository to your composer.json and disable proc_open from packagist :

   ```
   repositories": [
       {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "http://127.0.0.1/server-composer/"
       },
       {
           "packagist": false
       }
   ],
   ```